# Visual Studio Code - Can't connect to localhost:9222

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I have installed Visual studio code and Node.JS (an older version) when I realized that I installed the old version of Node.JS I have uninstalled and re-installed the newer version, but somehow VSC still thinks that an older version is on my PC.

VSC "About" panel shows the following:

Version: 1.79.2 (user setup)
Commit: 695af097c7bd098fbf017ce3ac85e09bbc5dda06
Date: 2023-06-14T08:57:04.379Z
Electron: 22.5.7
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
**Node.js: 16.17.1**
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

[image: Node.JS version]

My problem is that I read that the older version of Node.JS there are some problems like I can't connect to localhost:9222, because everytime I am trying to run the following:

```
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debugger",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9222,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "webRoot": "${cwd}/"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am receiving the following error message:
[image: Error message]

Localhost Power BI certificate is installed on my PC.

[image]

Comment: re-launch VSCode to update environment vars? or even the whole PC?

Comment: I did it, re-installed the whole VSCode, but still the same

Comment: The node version of VSCode is which your VSCode version was built with. Doesn't relate to your system's node version and doesn't affect your node projects.

Your connection problem looks like also not related to the node version but rather to a configuration problem.

Comment: Maybe it can't find the debuggable target because you are not launching with --inspect. Visual Studio Code indeed is an Electron app, so it can use his own version of NodeJS.